# How to open and manipulate multiple text files all at the same time after selecting them with tkinter?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file, tkinter

Python noob here:

I am trying to speed up my file-editing through selecting multiple text files with tkinter, but I don't know how to open them and edit them all at once to remove `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='xyz.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>`

My code:

```
import re
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames

filename = askopenfilenames()

f = open(filename, "r")

lines = f.readlines()

f.close()

f = open(filename, "w")

for line in lines:
    line = re.sub('<(.|\n)*?>', "", line)
    f.write(line)

f.close()
```

It works with askopenfilename (not plural) and I remove the unwanted string just fine.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not working with each file name within the list. So instead you need to run a for loop over your list created from `askopenfilenames()`.

According to the tooltip in my IDE `askopenfilenames()` returns a list.

```
def askopenfilenames(**options):
    """Ask for multiple filenames to open

    Returns a list of filenames or empty list if
    cancel button selected
    """
    options["multiple"] = 1
    return Open(**options).show()
```

I changed your variable filename to filenames as it is a list and this makes more sense. Then I ran a for loop over this list and it should work as desired.

Try this below code.

```
import re
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames

filenames = askopenfilenames()

for filename in filenames:
    f = open(filename, "r")

    lines = f.readlines()

    f.close()

    f = open(filename, "w")

    for line in lines:
        line = re.sub('<(.|\n)*?>', "", line)
        f.write(line)

    f.close()
```

With a couple of if statements we can prevent the most common errors that may come up if you select nothing or select file types that are not compatable.

```
import re
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames

filenames = askopenfilenames()

if filenames != []:
    if filenames[0] != "":
        for filename in filenames:
            f = open(filename, "r")

            lines = f.readlines()

            f.close()

            f = open(filename, "w")

            for line in lines:
                line = re.sub('<(.|\n)*?>', "", line)
                f.write(line)

            f.close()
```

Comment: @Waldkamel glad to help. Please select the check mark next to my answer to show your problem has been resolved.

Comment: Which IDE are you using, if I may ask? This extra information from the tooltip would be very helpful in my learning process!

Comment: Eclipse with the Pydev add-on.

Comment: thanks again! I'll make sure to download it. Check mark is selected :-)